# Porque me marca de rojo la implementación de una librería en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy intentando implementar la siguiente librería, pero me lo marca de ojo , adjunto imagen también

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 30

implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The android.support-packaged libraries are deprecated and replaced by individually-versioned Jetpack libraries packaged as androidx.

Como dice la documentación oficial, la Support Library ya no tiene soporte. En su lugar debes usar Android Jetpack:

```
// librería java
implementation "androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0"
// librería con funciones extras exclusivas para kotlin
implementation "androidx.palette:palette-ktx:1.0.0"
```